# Removing the shadow created by a dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

How do you remove the shadow from a dialog in android?

Thanks

Peter,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: this removes background tint, but not the shadow